# Proxy for mocking requests to remote servers

Tags: ios, testing, proxy

I'am testing my iOS app, that use internet for getting data. Sometimes internet is unavailable, so I need a way to redirect remote connection to file on my local computer. I'am only need to test api. I have unit-tests with mocks,but they do not solve the problem completely.

I can setup server, and redirect connections to localhost, but I think there is a less complex and more accurate solution. Do you have any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: can you share the method that you want to test

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to make a Unit Test for  remote connection or for method that use a remote connection to get data ? 
in case is a remote connection i don't know why you want to test it because for me it's an apple feature.
if because your method use a remote connection to get data, so i think that you have to broke this dependency by mocking the remote connection process and return something that you expect

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution of my problem was to use framework for mocking network traffic: BarricadeKit (MMBarricade).

With this framework I can configure local server in iOS app. Framework will redirect all outgoing network traffic to this server.